# 3d rotation representation for multiple turns

Tags: rotations, quaternions, robotics

Currently I am learning to use quaternions to represent rotations in the 3D world. The task is to make the object rotate for a given angle in certain time. I am now wondering *which type of rotation representation* I should use and *what kind of measure* I should use to get the difference between two rotations.

Quaternion is useful and popular in such a field and it greatly satisfies all my need except for one thing. The measure I am using right now is like
$$
d(q_1,q_2)=1-(q_1\cdot q_2)^2
$$
since $-q$ and $q$ represent the same rotation. The problem is that if I want the object to rotate $360^{\circ}$, while it doesn't rotate at all, the distance of such two quaternions is zero then. I think it is not a problem of the measure since the quaternion itself does not contain the status imformation of the accumulative angle with respective to the difference of $2k\pi$.

I am wondering if there is a kind of rotation representation which is easy to use as quaternions while at the same time saves the information of the accumulative angle. Euler angles and rotation matrices cannot solve the problem. Or should I track along the trajectory to finish the job. Also, I am thinking about somehow differentiate the whole process and integrate back to get the trajectory information but I could not figure it out clearly. Is it a good way to try?

Appreciate your help.

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, then what you want are quaternion exponentials. If $v$ is the unit imaginary quaternion representing the rotation axis, then $q = e^{\theta v/2}$ is the quaternion representing rotation about $v$ by angle $\theta$ according to the right hand rule. This means you can interpolate such a rotation over a time $T$ with the function $t \mapsto e^{t\theta v/2T}$.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I read something about quaternion exponentials and I think it is just another form of quaternions. If I get a final $q$ in practice somehow after calculation, it will be exactly the same as quaternions that I cannot figure out the difference between $\theta$ w.r.t. $2k\pi$. Am I understanding it correctly?

Comment: Unit quaternions give you a double cover $SO(3)$; they form the group [$Spin(3)$](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_group). That is to say that both $q$ and $-q$ effect the same rotation. You could use this to distinguish rotations by $4k\pi$ from rotations by $(4k+2)\pi$. For instance, rotation by an angle of $0$ is $e^0 = 1$ but rotation by $2\pi$ around an axis $v$ is $e^{2\pi v/2} = -1$. You "rotate" a quaternion $q_0$ by another quaternion $q$ by multiplying: $qq_0$.

Comment: You could also consider just storing your rotations as an axis-angle pair $(v,\theta)$ and allow $\theta$ to accumulate however you wish. If you want to track the "accumulated angle" over arbitrary 3D rotations, not just those in a plane, then you need to define what that means since a priori that doesn't make any sense to me.